# How to write a Kusto query to get previous month logs in sentinel?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerquery, kql, azure-sentinel

`| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)`
only gives me the last 30 days logs and I'm searching for a query to get previous month logs from a table, so I can export it directly into Power BI.

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it below.  I am showing two ways.  The 'easy' way is to just hand jam the dates in for the month.  The harder way requires you to use the `make_datetime` function.

```
// The Easy 'Manual' Way
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= datetime('2021-08-01') and TimeGenerated <= datetime('2021-08-31')
// Automated Way
let lastmonth = getmonth(datetime(now)) -1;
let year = getyear(datetime(now)); 
let monthEnd = endofmonth(datetime(now),-1); 
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= make_datetime(year,lastmonth,01) and TimeGenerated <= monthEnd
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-datetimefunction

Comment: came up with an issue, this works only for 31 days months :/

Comment: fixed this issue by using the `endofmonth()` function.

Comment: I don't think this will work for for query's executed in January where you need the data of December last year not current year

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add on to @Ken W MSFT's great query, by suggesting this for the automation

let time_start = startofmonth(datetime(now), -1);
let time_end = endofmonth(datetime(now),-1);
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (time_start .. time_end)